# No se ejecuta consulta al llenar campo de usuario y contraseña

Tags: mysql, mysqli, revisión-de-código

He hecho esta web con una base de datos muy simple basada en PHP y MySQLi. A la hora de llenar el campo Usuario y Contraseña me sale que no se ejecuta la consulta, o mejor dicho, el sistema espera un resultado de MySQLi. Creo hice bien todo, pero no sé si el método `POST` no está funcionando bien.

Dejo el código fuente aquí:

```
<?php
include_once "includes/conex.php";
//Form Data
$UserID = $_POST['UserID'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
//Start Insert
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($UserID)) {
        die('You didn\'t specify an Account Name!');
    }
    if (empty($pass)) {
        die('You didn\'t enter a password!');
    }
    //Check if UserID Exists
    {
        $useruid = mysqli_query($conexion, 'SELECT * FROM admin WHERE UserID = \'' . $UserID . '\' and pass = \'' . $pass . '\'');
        IF(mysqli_fetch_array($useruid)==0)
            die ('Cuenta No existe.');
        else
            die ('Sin Exito');


}}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 2.0 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/logo.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>
Registro y control de bienes nacionales de la aldea universitaria Jose Felix Rivas
</h2>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<center>
<form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>" method="POST">
<center>
</center>
<table>
<tr><td>Usuario:</td><td><input type="text" name="UserID" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Clave:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass" /></td></tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="Ingresar al Registro de bienes Nacionales" name="submit" /></p>
</form>
</center>
<img src="images/header_left.gif" HEIGHT=75 ALIGN =center>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

La creacion de la Tabla es la siguiente

```
CREATE TABLE `admin` (
  `Admin` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pw` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Exactamente, cual es el error que te muestra en pantalla?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MS\index.php on line 17
Cuenta No existe.

Comment: Pero en tu tabla `admin` no aparecen los campos `UserId` ni `pass` que invocas en el `select` O_o.... Si esa es tu tabla en verdad, entonces por eso no te devuelve un resultset, sino ese booleano :o

Answer (score 1):

Primero tienes un problema grave en la consulta, los nombres de los campos de tu tabla que tienes en tu sentencia no son los que tienes en tu tabla. Estas comparando UserId cuando en tu tabla tienes Admin, y pass cuando en tu tabla tienes pw, ten en cuenta eso primeramente.

Segundo, estas utilizando mysqli_fetch_array, y esto lo que te da es un array con todos los datos que traiga la consulta, debes utilizar mysqli_num_rows para ver cuantas coincidencias trae la consulta y allí si hacer la comparación `==0;`

Ahora tu código es muy vulnerable a inyección SQL, puedes utilizar sentencias preparadas, utilizando PDO. De todas maneras tratando de no mover mucho tu código

Prueba con esto:

```
<?php
 include_once "includes/conex.php";
 //Form Data
 $UserID = $_POST['UserID'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];
 //Start Insert
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   if (empty($UserID)) {
     die('You didn\'t specify an Account Name!');
   }
   if (empty($pass)) {
     die('You didn\'t enter a password!');
   }
 }

 $useruid = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Admin = "$UserID" and pw = "$pass" ");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($useruid)==0)
        die ('Cuenta No existe.');
    else
        die ('Sin Exito');
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

El `mysqli_fetch_array` es para iterar el resultado de un query, en el caso de que requieras mostrar el resultado en el `front-end`

Para hacer la validación que requieres es necesario utilizar el `mysqli_num_rows`,quedando de esta forma

```
$useruid = mysqli_query($conexion, 'SELECT * FROM admin WHERE UserID = \'' . $UserID . '\' and pw = \'' . $pass . '\'');
    if(mysqli_num_rows($useruid)==0)
        die ('Cuenta No existe.');
    else
        die ('Sin Exito');
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la tabla los campos son:

1. Admin
2. pw

Con lo que la consulta debería ser esta:

```
 $useruid = mysqli_query($conexion, 'SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Admin =\'' . $UserID . '\' and pw= \'' . $pass . '\'');
```